# Fluent Nhibernate generating incorrect query resulting in Cartesian product instead of single row

Tags: nhibernate, orm, fluent-nhibernate

After trying numerous things, I am still unable to figure out the right way to query the following relationship using Fluent NHibernate.
This would otherwise have been an easier task if I had to write SQL queries. Hope to get some better advice to avoid N+1 issue and unoptimized auto-generated SQL queries.

I have the following relationship which goes something as below :

Tags can have media content (Images of various predefined sizes, videos, documents etc.) associated with it.
 - 1 Tags can have multiple Media Items mapped to it (Lets's say images with dimension 32x32, 64x64, 600x100, 0 or more Videos)
 - Every media item is mapped to a media description which helps in identifying the size and type of the media
 - The same media item can be used by a different tag. Example, having a generic image for all tags which do not have any icons.

[image: ERD for your reference]

**Entities:**
Media

```
public class Media:IEntity
{
        private ICollection<TagMedia> _tagMedia;  

        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string FilePath { get; set; }
        public virtual MediaType MediaType { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<TagMedia> TagMedia
        {
            get { return _tagMedia?? (_tagMedia= new List<TagMedia>()); }
            protected set { _tagMedia= value; }
        }
}
```

Tag

```
public class Tag:IEntity
    {
        private ICollection<TagMedia> _tagMedia;
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<TagMedia> TagMedia
        {
            get { return _tagMedia?? (_tagMedia= new List<TagMedia>()); }
            set { _tagMedia= value; }
        }
}
```

TagMedia

```
public class TagMedia :IEntity
{
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual Media Media { get; set; }
        public virtual Tag Tag { get; set; }

        public virtual DateTime AddedOn { get; set; }
}
```

MediaType

```
public class MediaType:IEntity
{
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string Description { get; set; }
}
```

**Mappings**

MediaMapping

```
public class MediaMapping : IAutoMappingOverride<Media>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<Media> mapping)
    {
         mapping.Map(c => c.FileName).CustomSqlType("varchar(60)").Not.Nullable();  
    }
}
```

TagMapping

```
public class TagMapping : IAutoMappingOverride<Tag>
    {
        public void Override(AutoMapping<Tag> mapping)
        {
            mapping.HasMany<TagMedia>(c => c.TagMedia)
                .KeyColumn("TagId")
                .Cascade.SaveUpdate()
                .BatchSize(25);

            mapping.BatchSize(25);
            mapping.DynamicUpdate();
            mapping.DynamicInsert();
        }
    }
```

TagMediaMapping

```
public class TagMediaMapping : IAutoMappingOverride<TagMedia>
    {
        public void Override(AutoMapping<TagMedia> mapping)
        {
            mapping.Map(c=>c.AddedOn);
        }
    }
```

**Query:**
The following query gets the cartesian product of all media mapped to the tag and does not eliminate records other than "Icon-16x16". I expect the ORM to return no more than one row.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
_session.Query<Tag>()
                .FetchMany(x => x.TagMedia)
                .ThenFetch(x => x.Media)
                .ThenFetch(x=>x.MediaType)
                .Where(c => c.Id == id 
                        && c.TaxonomyMedia.Any(x=>x.Media.MediaType.Description== "Icon-16x16")) 
                .SingleOrDefault();
```

Generated SQL:

```
exec sp_executesql N'select * 
from [Tag] Tag0_ left outer join [TagMedia] Tagme1_ on Tag0_.TagId=Tagme1_.TagId 
left outer join [Media] media2_ on Tagme1_.MediaId=media2_.MediaId 
left outer join [MediaType] mediatype3_ on media2_.MediaTypeId=mediatype3_.MediaTypeId 
where Tag0_.TagId=@p0 
and (exists (select Tagme4_.TagMediaId 
                    from [TagMedia] Tagme4_ inner join [Media] media5_ on Tagme4_.MediaId=media5_.MediaId inner join [MediaType] mediatype6_ on media5_.MediaTypeId=mediatype6_.MediaTypeId where Tag0_.TagId=Tagme4_.TagId and mediatype6_.MediaTypeDescription=@p1))',N'@p0 int,@p1 nvarchar(4000)',@p0=102,@p1=N'Icon-16x16'
go
```

Answer (score 0):

the SingleOrDefault function is a LINQ function and not implemented by NHibernate. Use .Take(1)
I think the solution is:

```
_session.Query<Tag>()
            .FetchMany(x => x.TagMedia)
            .ThenFetch(x => x.Media)
            .ThenFetch(x=>x.MediaType)
            .Where(c => c.Id == id 
                    && c.TaxonomyMedia.Any(x=>x.Media.MediaType.Description== "Icon-16x16")) 
            .Take(1)
            .SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: It returns a record without any Media. Even when there are 4 media items associated to the Tag out of which one is Icon-16x16. Any other suggestions?

Comment: question: I think I don't really get what you really want. The media type for a tag, where the Description is "Icon-16x16"? Is that correct?

Comment: A tag can have multiple media associated with it of various sizes, Icon-32x32, Icon-128x128, video-720p,video-1080p etc. For a given tag id and media type description, I wanted to fetch details of the tag along with media name and path. If there exists no media mapped to the tag then Media can be returned empty but I still require Tag information.